# How do I call another method from within the same class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am aware that there are previous questions of this but I have tried the answers and still fail with error:

> __salaryTypeFromWeekday is not a function.

I have tried using "bind" inside constructor, "this" for calling the function, and also changing the function declaration to include the "this" keyword.

```
class SalaryType {
  constructor(selectedSalaryType) {
    this.selectedSalaryType = selectedSalaryType;
    this.__salaryTypeFromWeekday = this.__salaryTypeFromWeekday.bind(this)
  }

  get selected() {
    return this.selectedSalaryType;
  }

  static __updateSalaryType(typeOfDayStr, statusStr)
  {
    var typeOfDay = parseInt(typeOfDayStr, 10);
    var status = parseInt(statusStr, 10);
    switch(typeOfDay) {
      case WEEK_DAY:
        this.selectedSalaryType = this.__salaryTypeFromWeekday(status);
        break;
    }
    return this.selectedSalaryType;
  }

  __salaryTypeFromWeekday(status) {
    switch(status) {
      case WORK_ATTENDANCE:
        return SALARY_KIND_NORMAL;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: this.__salaryTypeFromWeekday(status); which returns something and will be put into this.selectedSalaryType.

Comment: Your code is a class definition. Can you post the code that causes your error ? + in your `__salaryTypeFromWeekday `method, what is WORK_ATTENDANCE ? it should be a variable or a string, otherwise it will throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: `__updateSalaryType` is marked as static, theres no `this` available.

Comment: WORK_ATTENDANCE is a global const outside the class but on the same js file. There is no problem. The problem lies with calling the __salaryTypeFromWeekday method.

Comment: @Lorenz show the code and context that actually __call__ the function causing your error. Note that you should avoid having global dependency inside your class even if _"it works"_

Comment: var salaryType = SalaryType.__updateSalaryType($('#work_day_kind_' + id).val(), $('#work_kind_' + id).val()); is the line that calls from blade. I'm using laravel. I was able to resolve the problem turning the __salaryTypeFromWeekday  to a static function since __updateSalaryType is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you call the __salaryTypeFromWeekdays from a *static* function, which does not have instance of "this", because it operates on the class and not on an instance. So you should either transform the __salaryTypeFromWeekdays to a static functino, or pass  __updateSalaryType an actual instance of the class and use it like:
`instance.__salaryTypeFromWeekdays`.

Comment: Thank you. I turned the __salaryTypeFromWeekdays function to a static function and it now works. I still need to use the "this" keyword when calling another static function. I'm a beginner to Javascript so Javascript classes seem hard for me.

Comment: @Lorenz Instead of making `__salaryTypeFromWeekdays` static, you should have made `__updateSalaryType` non-static. It clearly operates on an instance (using `this.selectedSalaryType`). Why did you make it `static` in the first place?

Comment: I was told by my boss to make the functions of the class I'm tasked to create as static. I changed them all to non-static and used the instance instead and it works too. Will have to talk to my boss about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lorenz Like Bergi said, it is usually better to have non-static than static functions. Your boss might have had a special reason tho, so it worth your while to sit with him and understand why he wanted them statics, you might be able to pick up some new way of thinking or concept you didn't know about :)
also, if my answer helped you i'd appreciate if you could mark it as "accepted" by clicking the "V" near my answer and vote it up :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the `bind` inside the constructor - simply defining the method as you have done should work as an instance method.

If you want a static method, you should use `static`:

```
static __salaryTypeFromweekday(status) {
  // ...
}
```